# Determine values of x for which series converges

Tags: real-analysis

Find all values of x for which the following series converges and determine the sum.

$$x+\frac{x}{1+x}+\frac{x}{(1+x)^2}+\frac{x}{(1+x)^3}+\dots$$

I know the basic definitions of convergence and how the proofs go. However, I am not understanding how to apply it to this one.

Comment: I can't see a sequence, I can just see an expression in $x$. Please use LaTex to clarify the sequence of interest and the review the wording of your question so that it is clearer.

Comment: I changed the post.

Comment: Do you mean the sequence $x, \frac{x}{1+x}, \frac{x}{(1+x)^2}, ...$ or the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x}{(1+x)^n}$?

Comment: The textbook states the problem exactly how it is in the question above.

Comment: now it’s better!!

Comment: The smallest typos make the biggest differences!

Comment: Hint: You can start by thinking about the absolute value $|1+x|$. E.g, does the series converges if $x=7$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x+\frac{x}{1+x}+\frac{x}{(1+x)^2}+\frac{x}{(1+x)^3}+\dots = x(1+r+r^2+ r^3+....)$$

With $$r= \frac {1}{1+x}$$

The geometric series converges to $$\frac {1}{1-r} = 1+\frac{1}{x}$$ for $|\frac {1}{1+x}|<1$

Thus the original series $$x+\frac{x}{1+x}+\frac{x}{(1+x)^2}+\frac{x}{(1+x)^3}+\dots =x(1+\frac{1}{x})=x+1$$

Provided that  $|\frac {1}{1+x}|<1$ which is $|x+1|>1$.

Answer (score 1):

Geometric sequence.  $a_n = a_0 r^{n-1}$
with $a_0 = x$ and $r = \frac{1}{1+x} $

$S_n$ : Sum of the sequence up to $n^{\text{th}}$ element.

$$S_n =\frac{a_0(1-r^n)}{1-r}= \frac{x-x\frac{1}{(1+x)^n}}{1-\frac{1}{1+x}}$$

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}S_n = \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{x-x\frac{1}{(1+x)^n}}{1-\frac{1}{1+x}}$$

The problem is the term $x\frac{1}{(1+x)^n}$
And using the hint from @Erxiem, you can get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac {x}{(x+1)^n} = \frac {(x+1)-1}{(x+1)^n} = \frac {1}{(x+1)^{n-1}} - \frac{1}{(x+1)^n}$

This series telescopes, and will equal $x+1 - \lim_\limits{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{(x+1)^n}$

The series converges when $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{(x+1)^n}$ is finite.

$x<-2$ or $x \ge 0$

Answer (score 0):

Use the ratio test on $\Sigma_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x}{(1+x)^n}$:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right| < 1$$
$$\Rightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac{x/(1+x)^{n+1}}{x/(1+x)^{n}} \right| < 1$$ $$\Rightarrow \left|\frac{1}{1+x}\right| < 1$$

And now we reach the same inequality as in Mohamed Riazi-Kermani's answer, so we have $|x+1| > 1$.